# Building a collection hierarchy using Google Docs API

Tags: python, gdata-api, google-docs-api

Is it possible to search for a specific collection, build a hierarchy of sub-collections and then download the contents of the parent collection while maintaining the hierarchy?

If this is possible, how would one start to implement the solution using the Python gData library (as a desktop application, not a web app)?